# Grabbing the row with the highest value from each group?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have data that looks like this:

```
Table
Group: "A" , Color: "Blue", Count: "400"
Group: "A" , Color: "Green", Count: "3"
Group: "A" , Color: "Yellow", Count: "6"
Group: "A" , Color: "Red", Count: "1"
Group: "B" , Color: "Purple", Count: "243"
Group: "B" , Color: "Green", Count: "2"
Group: "B" , Color: "Yellow", Count: "7"
```

How can I query this data to get for each group the most popular (by count) color.  So the result would look like this:

```
Result
Group: "A", Color: "Blue"
Group: "B", Color: "Purple"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT Group, Color
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT Group, Max(CAST(Count as int)) as Ct
            FROM MyTable
            GROUP BY Group) Sub
   ON sub.group = t.group
   AND sub.ct = t.count
```

As an aside, don't name a field `GROUP`, or `COUNT`.  They are keywords and will lead to headaches and heartbreak.

Comment: +1, `t.count` is varchar. make a conversion when comparing to `sub.ct`.

Comment: @aF. - good point.  I actually should do a CAST in the subquery since as written `40 > 300`

Comment: If you had two Blue 400s, you'd get two records back.  Might want to distinct the final result.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
SELECT    t.Group,
          t.Color,
          t.Count
FROM     (SELECT   Group,
                   Color,
                   Count,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Group ORDER BY CAST(Count AS INT) DESC) AS num
          FROM Table) AS t
WHERE     t.num = 1
```

Comment: `RANK()` might be a better choice, as there might be several colours with the same maximum count.

Comment: What is the difference? After all, only the first row is taken in a group. You can adjust the ORDER BY clause to add priority for the Colors for case, when the Counts are the same.

Comment: If that was what you assumed (*‘only the first row is taken in a group’*), then, of course, `ROW_NUMBER()` is a way to go. But if the OP meant to include all the occurrences of the top count from every group, even if some groups contained more than one, then `ROW_NUMBER()` would give you incomplete results.