# How to select data rows from sql server with the maximum value?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a sql server table named Student like below:

[image]

I wish to select the students with the highest score from each class, which shall produce the output like this:

[image]

Due to some constraint, I can't be sure how  many unique class names would exist in the table. My stored procedure is :

```
  create procedure selectBestStudent
  as
  begin
  select Name, max(TestScore)
  from [TestDB1].[dbo].[StudentTest]
  group by Name
  end
```

But the result is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: see: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grabbing the row with the highest value from each group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180283/grabbing-the-row-with-the-highest-value-from-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT Name, Class, TestScore
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Class, TestScore,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Class 
                            ORDER BY TestScore DESC) AS rn
  FROM StudentTest) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER` enumerates records within each `Class` partition: the `ORDER BY` clause guarantees that the record having the greatest `TestScore` value is assigned a value equal to 1.

**Note:** To handle ties you can use `RANK` in place of `ROW_NUMBER`. This way you can get *all* students that share the *same maximum* `TestScore` for the *same* `Class`.

Comment: You can try adding a `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Class)`

Comment: Thank you :) I really appreciate your reply :)

Comment: I hate them.. take your +1 back:)

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this goal with NOT EXISTS()

```
SELECT * FROM Student s
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select 1 FROM Student t
                 where t.class = s.class
                      and t.testScore > s.testScore)
```

This will select only those rows that doesn't have a row with a higher value on testScore

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have a problem with the Group By and the MAX() when there are multiple people with the same score in a class.

I solved it with a fetch if you don't know yet what this is, you can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms180152%28v=sql.120%29.aspx,). It's easier than it looks at the beginning!

I know that might be a horrible way to do it but its's easy to understand and it worked! :D

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

DECLARE @class char(10), @testscore int;
DECLARE @result Table
(
    Name char(10),
    Class  char(10),
    TestScore int
);
-- Get Classes and their Maxima 
DECLARE TestScore_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT [class], MAX([testscore]) FROM [student] GROUP BY [class];

OPEN TestScore_cursor;

-- Perform the first fetch.
FETCH NEXT FROM TestScore_cursor INTO @class, @testscore;

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   -- Search Students by Class and Score and add them to tempTable @result
   INSERT INTO @result SELECT [name], [class], [testscore] From [student] where [testScore] = @testscore AND [class] = @class;

   FETCH NEXT FROM TestScore_cursor INTO @class, @testscore;
END

-- Show the Result
SELECT * FROM @result;

CLOSE TestScore_cursor;
DEALLOCATE TestScore_cursor;
GO
```